# Product of all ints in array besides that an index i

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge

I'm looking for a better implementation of the algorithm.

```
/*
 * You have an ordered array X of n integers. Find the array M containing
 * elements where Mi is the product of all integers in X except for Xi.
 * You may not use division. You can use extra memory.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

/*!
 * Class used to generate sequences with helper function
 */
template <class T>
class sequence : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{
    T val;
public:
    sequence(T init) : val(init) {}
    T operator *() { return val; }
    sequence &operator++() { ++val; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(sequence const &other) { return val != other.val; }
};

template <class T>
sequence<T> gen_seq(T const &val) {
    return sequence<T>(val);
}



static const int N = 3;
std::stack<int> stk;
std::queue<int> que;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> seq(gen_seq(1), gen_seq(N + 1));
  for (int x = 0, y = N - 1; x < N && y >= 0; ++x, --y) {
    if (x == 0 && y == N - 1) {
      stk.push(1);
      que.push(1);
    } else {
      stk.push(stk.top() * seq[x - 1]);
      que.push(que.back() * seq[y + 1]);
    }
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < N; ++x) {
    std::cout << (stk.top() * que.front()) << std::endl;
    stk.pop();
    que.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some comments on the existing code:

```
/*
 * You have an ordered array X of n integers. Find the array M containing
 * elements where Mi is the product of all integers in X except for Xi.
 * You may not use division. You can use extra memory
 */
```

You don't have anything called `X` in the code, or generate `M`, so this comment could be better

```
static const int N = 3;
std::stack<int> stk;
std::queue<int> que;
```

Why use globals? Also, try to name variables by what they *do* or *represent*, rather than their type.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

For that matter, why put the logic in `main` where you can't test it?
I would hope to see something structured like:

```
std::vector<int> products(std::vector<int> const &X)
{
    auto n = X.size();
    std::vector<int> M(n, 1);

    // ... algorithm ...

    return M;
}

int main()
{
    static const int N = 3;
    std::vector<int> seq(gen_seq(1), gen_seq(N + 1))
    std::vector<int> result = products(seq);
    // print the result
    // or assert correctness
}
```

Or possibly several test functions, each called from `main`.

As for the algorithm itself, its working isn't really clear, and that's where comments would be useful. I'm sure *you* have a deep intuitive understanding of why your nameless stack and queue generate the right results, but without a lot of effort I don't. In six months' time, you may not either.

Your loop can be cleaner anyway; instead of:

```
  for (int x = 0, y = N - 1; x < N && y >= 0; ++x, --y) {
    if (x == 0 && y == N - 1) {
      stk.push(1);
      que.push(1);
    } else {
      stk.push(stk.top() * seq[x - 1]);
      que.push(que.back() * seq[y + 1]);
    }
  }
```

we can:

1. move the special case `if (x == 0 ...` outside
2. then, you only have to iterate over the values used in the second branch (so `1 <= x < N`, `N-2 >= y >= 0`)
3. but we only use `x-1` and `y+1` in the body of the loop, so simplify this to `0 <= x < N-1` and `N-1 >= y >= 0` and just use `x` and `y` in the body
4. notice that the two conditions (`x < N-1 && y >= 0`) will always agree, so we don't have to test both

to get:

```
  stk.push(1);
  que.push(1);
  for (int x = 0, y = N-1; x < N-1; ++x, --y)
  {
    stk.push(stk.top() * seq[x]);
    que.push(que.back() * seq[y]);
  }
```

---

and a simpler implementation:

```
std::vector<int> products(std::vector<int> const &X)
{
    auto n = X.size();
    std::vector<int> M(n, 1); // initialise all values to 1

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // set Mj <= Mj * Xi for all j != i
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (j != i) M[j] *= X[i];
    }
    return M;
}
```

This one uses no extra memory but is `O(n^2)`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Though the O(n^2) algorithm is what I was trying to get away from. It is clear, but for very large data sets it is not efficient.

Answer (score 5):

At least IMO, this can be solved quite a bit more cleanly than the examples above show. The "trick" to solving the problem efficiently is to produce running products, starting from both the left *and* the right side of the input array. To keep some of the later code simple, it's easiest to append a `1` to the beginning of one of those, and the end of the other.

For example, given an input like: [2, 3, 5, 7] we'd produce intermediate results like:

```
X             2    3    5     7
left          1    2    6    30    210
right    210  105  35   7     1
```

Just to be sure we're clear, the `left` holds running products starting from the left--the first item is a `1` we put there "artificially". The second is 1*2. The third is 1*2*3. The fourth is 1*2*3*5, and the last is 1*2*3*5*7.

In `right` is pretty much the same, *except* that it's starting from the right instead of the left. So, the first item (starting from the right) is (again) the 1 we insert. Then 1*7, 1*7*5, 1*7*5*3, and 1*7*5*3*2.

Now, to compute each result, we multiply an item in `left` by an item in `right`. As I've lined things up in the table above, the items from `left` and `right` that are verticall aligned are multiplied to produce each result (and the last item of `left` and first item of `right` are simply ignored).

Translating that into C++, we get something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::deque<int> X{2, 3, 5, 7};

    std::deque<int> left;
    std::deque<int> right;

    left.push_back(1);

    int temp = 1;

    std::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), std::back_inserter(left),
        [&temp](int i) { temp *= i; return temp; });

    temp = 1;

    std::transform(X.rbegin(), X.rend(), std::front_inserter(right),
        [&temp](int i) { temp *= i; return temp; });

    right.push_back(1);

    std::transform(left.begin(), left.end()-1,
        right.begin()+1,
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"),
        [](int i, int j) { return i * j; });
}
```

That produces the following result:

```
105     70      42      30
```

Given \$N\$ inputs, this uses \$O(N)\$ extra space for `right` and `left`, and \$O(N)\$ time complexity (three traversals of \$N\$ items each).

Right now, this code uses `+` on one of the iterators and `-` on another, limiting the iterators to random access. If desired, it would be fairly trivial to use `std::advance` (or just `++` and `--`) to increment the iterators without the requirement for random access. On the other hand, there seems to be little gain from doing so--in theory it would allow us to use (for example) linked lists instead of `deque`s, but that seems unlikely to provide any real advantage.

If you were going to process large collections, you'd have another serious problem: the numbers involved would quick grow much larger than a `long` or even `long long` could accommodate. If the collection was very large at all, you'd probably need to use some sort of big integer type to represent the product.